# How to make separate Apache configuration file for multiple ports?

Tags: apache-httpd

I am running Apache webserver on CentOS.
I want to configure two ports, port 80 and port 8081. Not in virtual host. But two separate config file for each port. Is it possible?

192.168.0.2 should to port 80 config file.
192.168.0.2:8081 should go to 8081 config file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L! From your description it's not exactly clear what you are trying to do. What are you configuring the port for? Is this part of a firewall rule, forwarding through a NAT, setting up an application to listen on those ports? It also might be helpful to explain what you have done so far, then the community will get an idea of your goals.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create another config file like */etc/httpd/conf.d/8081.conf* and configure apache to open another listener port.

```
Listen 8081
```

With this setting, you can only serve the same contents the main server is configured for. Any setting you put into here like `DocumentRoot` would overwrite the main server's configuration.
So, if you want to serve different contents on the ports you have to work with `VirtualHosts`.

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/8081
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart your apache server after config changes.

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my confusing question as I am just learning now. I wanted to make multiple instance in my Apache server. I really appreciated your answer. I found the answer and did it successfully. **Thank you so much. :)**

What I did was simply copy httpd.conf file and make a copy of it and changed port 8081 and few other things.

```
cp -p /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd2.conf

vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd2.conf 
Include conf.d2/*.conf 
Listen 8081
PidFile run/httpd.pid2

/usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd2.conf -k start
service httpd start
```

Comment: This answer doesn’t actually resolve the problem permanently.  Sure, you’ve got a second httpd running, but it won’t start automatically. You’d need to create a separate new instance of the httpd.service.  Or just use a virtualhost like most of the rest of the Linux community.